# Rock Paper Scissors Java Decide

Tags: java

Basically Im trying to get it to give you the option to type Rock,Paper or Scissors, but in order to get Paper for example I need to type rock first and then it will read the line of code for me to get paper if that makes sense,

```
    public static String decideString() {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (userInput.nextLine().contentEquals("Rock")) {
        System.out.println("You have chosen rock");
    } else if (userInput.nextLine().contentEquals("Paper")) {
        System.out.println("You have chosen paper");
    } else if (userInput.nextLine().contentEquals("Scissors")) {
        System.out.println("You have chosen scissors");
    }
```

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: Do not call `netxLine()` inside your If condition. Call it outside ans store the result in a variable. Here you are calling it 3 times, so you read three lines each time, that's why it does not behave as you want

Comment: Can you give an example of your current and desired output for the input you described?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code.

```
public static String decideString() {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String in = userInput.nextLine();
    if (in.contentEquals("Rock")) {
        System.out.println("You have chosen rock");
    } else if (in.contentEquals("Paper")) {
        System.out.println("You have chosen paper");
    } else if (in.contentEquals("Scissors")) {
        System.out.println("You have chosen scissors");
    }
```

Comment: This works what was the difference other than the String you made?

Comment: @OnkarMusale You found the solution.  But your answer would be better if you explain it. What does OP is doing wrong ? Why your code correct it ?

Comment: yeah sure. @DylanHussain was asking user to input data every time and compared it to string immediately. you can use switch here to improve redability of code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using '.nextLine()' method inside each if statement, it will advance the current line every time it checks for a condition. If i understood you properly, you want user to enter only one input and the logic should print what they have chosen. In that case, the below code might help you.

The best practice is to use the Scanner object(scobj) only once and to store it in a variable (userInput) and later you can compare with the help of the variable in if statements.

```
    Scanner scobj = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = scobj.nextLine();

    if (userInput.contentEquals("Rock")) {
        System.out.println("You have chosen rock");
    } else if (userInput.contentEquals("Paper")) {
        System.out.println("You have chosen paper");
    } else if (userInput.contentEquals("Scissors")) {
        System.out.println("You have chosen scissors");
    }
```